# Insert huge Stripe object into MySQL blob fail

Tags: php, mysql, json, pdo, stripe-payments

My software acquires various payment data and inserts that data into a database via 2 (actually 3) queries.

One works fine.

The other ->

```
$statement2->execute();
```

does not.

The one that does not is trying to insert a pretty large JSON object from Stripe gateway into a blob.
That's the only significance between the two.

No error, but no data is ever inserted, not any field, as far and the failing query is concerned.

The other non object/blob query works/adds/updates just fine.

How do I get Stripe object data into a MySQL blob?

```
<?php
        session_start();
        require_once('sconfig.php');
        require_once('mail/config.php');
        try{
                $token  = $_POST['stripeToken'];

                $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
                        'email' => $_SESSION['SESS_EMAIL'],
                        'card'  => $token
                ));
                $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
                        'customer' => $customer->id,
                        'amount' => $_SESSION['PLAN'],
                        'currency' => 'usd'
                ));

        } catch (Exception $e) {
                echo "<br>";
                echo "Handle your exception fool!";
        }

        $pdo = new PDO(
                'mysql:host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_DATABASE,
                DB_USER,
                DB_PASSWORD
        );
        //here we insert plan into the database following purchase
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, true);

        $session_var = $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'];


        //ATTENTION!!!  All of these variable need to be changed when price gets changed
        if($_SESSION['PLAN'] === '3500'){
                $plan_var = 1;
                echo $plan_var;
                $payment = $_SESSION['PLAN'];
                $sql = 'UPDATE accounting SET active = 1, plan = :plan_var WHERE id = :session_var';
                $sql2 = 'INSERT INTO transactions (customer_object, charge_object, payment) VALUES(:customer, :charge, :payment)';
                $statement2 = $pdo->prepare($sql2);
                $statement2->bindParam(':payment', $payment, PDO::PARAM_INT, 20);
                $statement2->bindParam(':customer', $customer, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
                $statement2->bindParam(':charge', $charge, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
                $user = $statement2->execute();
                var_dump($payment);
                echo '<br>';
                echo '<br>';
                var_dump($customer);
                echo '<br>';
                echo '<br>';
                var_dump($charge);
        }
        else if($_SESSION['PLAN'] === '2500'){
                $plan_var = 2;
                echo $plan_var;
                $payment = $_SESSION['PLAN'];
                $sql = 'UPDATE accounting SET active = 1, plan = :plan_var WHERE id = :session_var';
                $sql2 = 'INSERT INTO transactions (customer_object, charge_object, payment) VALUES(:customer, :charge, :payment)';
                $statement2 = $pdo->prepare($sql2);
                $statement2->bindParam(':payment', $payment, PDO::PARAM_INT, 20);
                $statement2->bindParam(':customer', $customer, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
                $statement2->bindParam(':charge', $charge, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
                $user = $statement2->execute();

        }
        else if($_SESSION['PLAN'] === 'NULL'){
                echo "Call a Dr. Something bad happened, or the programmer needs to be fired";

                header("location: ../index.php?p=failed");
        }
        else {
                echo "This looks like a paid invoice. Thank you!";
                $plan_var = 9;
                echo '<br>';
                echo $plan_var;
                echo '<br>';
                echo '<pre>' . print_r($_SESSION, TRUE) . '</pre>';
                $payment = $_SESSION['PAYMENT'];
                $invoice_num = $_SESSION['INVOICE_NUM'];
                $sql = 'UPDATE accounting SET plan = :plan_var WHERE id = :session_var';
                $sql3 = 'INSERT INTO transactions (invoice_num, payment) VALUES(:invoice_num, :payment)';
                $statement3 = $pdo->prepare($sql3);
                $statement3->bindParam(':payment', $payment, PDO::PARAM_INT, 20);
                $statement3->bindParam(':invoice_num', $invoice_num, PDO::PARAM_STR, 255);
                $user = $statement3->execute();
                //header("location: ../index.php?p=success");
        }
        $statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);

        $statement->bindParam(':plan_var', $plan_var, PDO::PARAM_STR, 1);
        $statement->bindParam(':session_var', $session_var, PDO::PARAM_STR, 1);
        $user = $statement->execute();

        var_dump($statement);

        //header("location: ../index.php?p=success");
?>
```

mysql desc:

```
mysql> desc transactions;
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| id              | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |
| trans_date      | timestamp    | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
| customer_object | blob         | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| charge_object   | blob         | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| invoice_num     | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| payment         | int(20)      | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

debug output:

```
1string(4) "3500"
```

'
'

```
    object(Stripe\Customer)#5 (5) { ["_opts":protected]=> object(Stripe\Util\RequestOptions)#4 (2) { ["headers"]=> array(0) { } ["apiKey"]=> string(32) "sk_07C5ukIdqxyDGFqIKB8f7TXqGGyQt" } ["_values":protected]=> array(18) { ["id"]=> string(18) "cus_5wTdY1eJMv14Vn" ["object"]=> string(8) "customer" ["created"]=> int(1427375148) ["livemode"]=> bool(false) ["description"]=> NULL ["email"]=> string(20) "brad@nyctelecomm.com" ["delinquent"]=> bool(false) ["metadata"]=> object(Stripe\AttachedObject)#6 (5) { ["_opts":protected]=> object(Stripe\Util\RequestOptions)#4 (2) { ["headers"]=> array(0) { } ["apiKey"]=> string(32) "sk_07C5ukIdqxyDGFqIKB8f7TXqGGyQt" } ["_values":protected]=> array(0) { } ["_unsavedValues":protected]=> object(Stripe\Util\Set)#10 (1) { ["_elts":"Stripe\Util\Set":private]=> array(0) { } } ["_transientValues":protected]=> object(Stripe\Util\Set)#11 (1) { ["_elts":"Stripe\Util\Set":private]=> array(0) { } } ["_retrieveOptions":protected]=> array(0) { } } ["subscriptions"]=> object(Stripe\Collection)#9 (5) { ["_opts":protected]=> object(Stripe\Util\RequestOptions)#4 (2) { ["headers"]=> array(0) { } ["apiKey"]=> string(32) "sk_07C5ukIdqxyDGFqIKB8f7TXqGGyQt" } ["_values":protected]=> array(6) { ["object"]=> string(4) "list" ["total_count"]=> int(0) ["has_more"]=> bool(false) ["url"]=> string(46) "/v1/customers/cus_5wTdY1eJMv14Vn/subscriptions" ["data"]=> array(0) { } ["count"]=> int(0) } ["_unsavedValues":protected]=> object(Stripe\Util\Set)#13 (1) { ["_elts":"Stripe\Util\Set":private]=> array(0) { } } ["_transientValues":protected]=> object(Stripe\Util\Set)#14 (1) { ["_elts":"Stripe\Util\Set":private]=> array(0) { } } ["_retrieveOptions":protected]=> array(0) { } } ["discount"]=> NULL ["account_balance"]=> int(0) ["currency"]=> NULL ["cards"]=> object(Stripe\Collection)#12 (5) { ["_opts":protected]=> object(Stripe\Util\RequestOptions)#4 (2) { ["headers"]=> array(0) { } ["apiKey"]=> string(32) "sk_07C5ukIdqxyDGFqIKB8f7TXqGGyQt" } ["_values":protected]=> array(6) { ["object"]=> string(4) "list" ["total_count"]=> int(1) ["has_more"]=> bool(false) ["url"]=> string(38) "/v1/customers/cus_5wTdY1eJMv14Vn/cards" ["data"]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(Stripe\Card)#15 (5) { ["_opts":protected]=> object(Stripe\Util\RequestOptions)#4 (2) { ["headers"]=> array(0) { } ["apiKey"]=> string(32) "sk_07C5ukIdqxyDGFqIKB8f7TXqGGyQt" } ["_values":protected]=> array(23) { ["id"]=> string(19) "card_5wTdTGQYMhh9ks" ["object"]=> string(4) "card" ["last4"]=> string(4) "4242" ["brand"]=> string(4) "Visa" ["funding"]=> string(6) "credit" ["exp_month"]=> int(3) ["exp_year"]=> int(2016) ["fingerprint"]=> string(16) "m9lnTq91BB5a3UMX" ["country"]=> string(2) "US" ["name"]=> string(13) "blah@blah.com" ["address_line1"]=> NULL ["address_line2"]=> NULL ["address_city"]=> NULL ["address_state"]=> NULL ["address_zip"]=> NULL ["address_country"]=> NULL ["cvc_check"]=> NULL ["address_line1_check"]=> NULL ["address_zip_check"]=> NULL ["dynamic_last4"]=> NULL ["metadata"]=> object(Stripe\AttachedObject)#18 (5) { ["_opts":protected]=> object(Stripe\Util\RequestOptions)#4 (2) { ["headers"]=> array(0) { } ["apiKey"]=> string(32) "sk_07C5ukIdqxyDGFqIKB8f7TXqGGyQt" } ["_values":protected]=> array(0) { } ["_unsavedValues":protected]=> object(Stripe\Util\Set)#22 (1) { ["_elts":"Stripe\Util\Set":private]=> array(0) { } } ["_transientValues":protected]=> object(Stripe\Util\Set)#23 (1) { ["_elts":"Stripe\Util\Set":private]=> array(0) { } } ["_retrieveOptions":protected]=> array(0) { } } ["customer"]=> string(18) "cus_5wTdY1eJMv14Vn" ["type"]=> string(4) "Visa" } ["_unsavedValues":protected]=> object(Stripe\Util\Set)#19 (1) { ["_elts":"Stripe\Util\Set":private]=> array(0) { } } ["_transientValues":protected]=> object(Stripe\Util\Set)#20 (1) { ["_elts":"Stripe\Util\Set":private]=> array(0) { } } ["_retrieveOptions":protected]=> array(0) { } } } ["count"]=> int(1) } ["_unsavedValues":protected]=> object(Stripe\Util\Set)#16 (1) { ["_elts":"Stripe\Util\Set":private]=> array(0) { } } ["_transientValues":protected]=> object(Stripe\Util\Set)#17 (1) { ["_elts":"Stripe\Util\Set":private]=> array(0) { } } ["_retrieveOptions":protected]=> array(0) { } } ["default_card"]=> string(19) "card_5wTdTGQYMhh9ks" ["sources"]=> object(Stripe\Collection)#21 (5) { ["_opts":protected]=> object(Stripe\Util\RequestOptions)#4 (2) { ["headers"]=> array(0) { } ["apiKey"]=> string(32) "sk_07C5ukIdqxyDGFqIKB8f7TXqGGyQt" } ["_values":protected]=> array(6) { ["object"]=> string(4) "list" ["total_count"]=> int(1) ["has_more"]=> bool(false) ["url"]=> string(40) "/v1/customers/cus_5wTdY1eJMv14Vn/sources" ["data"]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(Stripe\Card)#24 (5) { ["_opts":protected]=> object(Stripe\Util\RequestOptions)#4 (2) { ["headers"]=> array(0) { } ["apiKey"]=> string(32) "sk_07C5ukIdqxyDGFqIKB8f7TXqGGyQt" } ["_values":protected]=> array(23) { ["id"]=> string(19) "card_5wTdTGQYMhh9ks" ["object"]=> string(4) "card" ["last4"]=> string(4) "4242" ["brand"]=> string(4) "Visa" ["funding"]=> string(6) "credit" ["exp_month"]=> int(3) ["exp_year"]=> int(2016) ["fingerprint"]=> string(16) "m9lnTq91BB5a3UMX" ["country"]=> string(2) "US" ["name"]=> string(13) "blah@blah.com" ["address_line1"]=> NULL ["address_line2"]=> NULL ["address_city"]=> NULL ["address_state"]=> NULL ["address_zip"]=> NULL ["address_country"]=> NULL ["cvc_check"]=> NULL ["address_line1_check"]=> NULL ["address_zip_check"]=> NULL ["dynamic_last4"]=> NULL ["metadata"]=> object(Stripe\AttachedObject)#27 (5) { ["_opts":protected]=> object(Stripe\Util\RequestOptions)#4 (2) { ["headers"]=> array(0) { } ["apiKey"]=> string(32) "sk_07C5ukIdqxyDGFqIKB8f7TXqGGyQt" } ["_values":protected]=> array(0) { } ["_unsavedValues":protected]=> object(Stripe\Util\Set)#31 (1) { ["_elts":"Stripe\Util\Set":private]=> array(0) { } } ["_transientValues":protected]=> object(Stripe\Util\Set)#32 (1) { ["_elts":"Stripe\Util\Set":private]=> array(0) { } } ["_retrieveOptions":protected]=> array(0) { } } ["customer"]=> string(18) "cus_5wTdY1eJMv14Vn" ["type"]=> string(4) "Visa" } ["_unsavedValues":protected]=> object(Stripe\Util\Set)#28 (1) { ["_elts":"Stripe\Util\Set":private]=> array(0) { } } ["_transientValues":protected]=> object(Stripe\Util\Set)#29 (1) { ["_elts":"Stripe\Util\Set":private]=> array(0) { } } ["_retrieveOptions":protected]=> array(0) { } } } ["count"]=> int(1) } ["_unsavedValues":protected]=> object(Stripe\Util\Set)#25 (1) { ["_elts":"Stripe\Util\Set":private]=> array(0) { } } ["_transientValues":protected]=> object(Stripe\Util\Set)#26 (1) { ["_elts":"Stripe\Util\Set":private]=> array(0) { } } ["_retrieveOptions":protected]=> array(0) { } } ["default_source"]=> string(19) "card_5wTdTGQYMhh9ks" ["active_card"]=> object(Stripe\Card)#30 (5) { ["_opts":protected]=> object(Stripe\Util\RequestOptions)#4 (2) { ["headers"]=> array(0) { } ["apiKey"]=> string(32) "sk_07C5ukIdqxyDGFqIKB8f7TXqGGyQt" } ["_values":protected]=> array(23) { ["id"]=> string(19) "card_5wTdTGQYMhh9ks" ["object"]=> string(4) "card" ["last4"]=> string(4) "4242" ["brand"]=> string(4) "Visa" ["funding"]=> string(6) "credit" ["exp_month"]=> int(3) ["exp_year"]=> int(2016) ["fingerprint"]=> string(16) "m9lnTq91BB5a3UMX" ["country"]=> string(2) "US" ["name"]=> string(13) "blah@blah.com" ["address_line1"]=> NULL ["address_line2"]=> NULL ["address_city"]=> NULL ["address_state"]=> NULL ["address_zip"]=> NULL ["address_country"]=> NULL ["cvc_check"]=> NULL ["address_line1_check"]=> NULL ["address_zip_check"]=> NULL ["dynamic_last4"]=> NULL ["metadata"]=> object(Stripe\AttachedObject)#33 (5) { ["_opts":protected]=> object(Stripe\Util\RequestOptions)#4 (2) { ["headers"]=> array(0) { } ["apiKey"]=> string(32) "sk_07C5ukIdqxyDGFqIKB8f7TXqGGyQt" } ["_values":protected]=> array(0) { } ["_unsavedValues":protected]=> object(Stripe\Util\Set)#37 (1) { ["_elts":"Stripe\Util\Set":private]=> array(0) { } } ["_transientValues":protected]=> object(Stripe\Util\Set)#38 (1) { ["_elts":"Stripe\Util\Set":private]=> array(0) { } } ["_retrieveOptions":protected]=> array(0) { } } ["customer"]=> string(18) "cus_5wTdY1eJMv14Vn" ["type"]=> string(4) "Visa" } ["_unsavedValues":protected]=> object(Stripe\Util\Set)#34 (1) { ["_elts":"Stripe\Util\Set":private]=> array(0) { } } ["_transientValues":protected]=> object(Stripe\Util\Set)#35 (1) { ["_elts":"Stripe\Util\Set":private]=> array(0) { } } ["_retrieveOptions":protected]=> array(0) { } } ["subscription"]=> NULL } ["_unsavedValues":protected]=> object(Stripe\Util\Set)#7 (1) { ["_elts":"Stripe\Util\Set":private]=> array(0) { } } ["_transientValues":protected]=> object(Stripe\Util\Set)#8 (1) { ["_elts":"Stripe\Util\Set":private]=> array(0) { } } ["_retrieveOptions":protected]=> array(0) { } } 

'<br>'
    object(Stripe\Charge)#39 (5) { ["_opts":protected]=> object(Stripe\Util\RequestOptions)#36 (2) { ["headers"]=> array(0) { } ["apiKey"]=> string(32) "sk_07C5ukIdqxyDGFqIKB8f7TXqGGyQt" } ["_values":protected]=> array(30) { ["id"]=> string(17) "ch_5wTdBr4oKHBPOp" ["object"]=> string(6) "charge" ["created"]=> int(1427375149) ["livemode"]=> bool(false) ["paid"]=> bool(true) ["status"]=> string(4) "paid" ["amount"]=> int(3500) ["currency"]=> string(3) "usd" ["refunded"]=> bool(false) ["source"]=> object(Stripe\Card)#40 (5) { ["_opts":protected]=> object(Stripe\Util\RequestOptions)#36 (2) { ["headers"]=> array(0) { } ["apiKey"]=> string(32) "sk_07C5ukIdqxyDGFqIKB8f7TXqGGyQt" } ["_values":protected]=> array(23) { ["id"]=> string(19) "card_5wTdTGQYMhh9ks" ["object"]=> string(4) "card" ["last4"]=> string(4) "4242" ["brand"]=> string(4) "Visa" ["funding"]=> string(6) "credit" ["exp_month"]=> int(3) ["exp_year"]=> int(2016) ["fingerprint"]=> string(16) "m9lnTq91BB5a3UMX" ["country"]=> string(2) "US" ["name"]=> string(13) "blah@blah.com" ["address_line1"]=> NULL ["address_line2"]=> NULL ["address_city"]=> NULL ["address_state"]=> NULL ["address_zip"]=> NULL ["address_country"]=> NULL ["cvc_check"]=> NULL ["address_line1_check"]=> NULL ["address_zip_check"]=> NULL ["dynamic_last4"]=> NULL ["metadata"]=> object(Stripe\AttachedObject)#43 (5) { ["_opts":protected]=> object(Stripe\Util\RequestOptions)#36 (2) { ["headers"]=> array(0) { } ["apiKey"]=> string(32) "sk_07C5ukIdqxyDGFqIKB8f7TXqGGyQt" } ["_values":protected]=> array(0) { } ["_unsavedValues":protected]=> object(Stripe\Util\Set)#47 (1) { ["_elts":"Stripe\Util\Set":private]=> array(0) { } } ["_transientValues":protected]=> object(Stripe\Util\Set)#48 (1) { ["_elts":"Stripe\Util\Set":private]=> array(0) { } } ["_retrieveOptions":protected]=> array(0) { } } ["customer"]=> string(18) "cus_5wTdY1eJMv14Vn" ["type"]=> string(4) "Visa" } ["_unsavedValues":protected]=> object(Stripe\Util\Set)#44 (1) { ["_elts":"Stripe\Util\Set":private]=> array(0) { } } ["_transientValues":protected]=> object(Stripe\Util\Set)#45 (1) { ["_elts":"Stripe\Util\Set":private]=> array(0) { } } ["_retrieveOptions":protected]=> array(0) { } } ["captured"]=> bool(true) ["card"]=> object(Stripe\Card)#46 (5) { ["_opts":protected]=> object(Stripe\Util\RequestOptions)#36 (2) { ["headers"]=> array(0) { } ["apiKey"]=> string(32) "sk_07C5ukIdqxyDGFqIKB8f7TXqGGyQt" } ["_values":protected]=> array(23) { ["id"]=> string(19) "card_5wTdTGQYMhh9ks" ["object"]=> string(4) "card" ["last4"]=> string(4) "4242" ["brand"]=> string(4) "Visa" ["funding"]=> string(6) "credit" ["exp_month"]=> int(3) ["exp_year"]=> int(2016) ["fingerprint"]=> string(16) "m9lnTq91BB5a3UMX" ["country"]=> string(2) "US" ["name"]=> string(13) "blah@blah.com" ["address_line1"]=> NULL ["address_line2"]=> NULL ["address_city"]=> NULL ["address_state"]=> NULL ["address_zip"]=> NULL ["address_country"]=> NULL ["cvc_check"]=> NULL ["address_line1_check"]=> NULL ["address_zip_check"]=> NULL ["dynamic_last4"]=> NULL ["metadata"]=> object(Stripe\AttachedObject)#49 (5) { ["_opts":protected]=> object(Stripe\Util\RequestOptions)#36 (2) { ["headers"]=> array(0) { } ["apiKey"]=> string(32) "sk_07C5ukIdqxyDGFqIKB8f7TXqGGyQt" } ["_values":protected]=> array(0) { } ["_unsavedValues":protected]=> object(Stripe\Util\Set)#53 (1) { ["_elts":"Stripe\Util\Set":private]=> array(0) { } } ["_transientValues":protected]=> object(Stripe\Util\Set)#54 (1) { ["_elts":"Stripe\Util\Set":private]=> array(0) { } } ["_retrieveOptions":protected]=> array(0) { } } ["customer"]=> string(18) "cus_5wTdY1eJMv14Vn" ["type"]=> string(4) "Visa" } ["_unsavedValues":protected]=> object(Stripe\Util\Set)#50 (1) { ["_elts":"Stripe\Util\Set":private]=> array(0) { } } ["_transientValues":protected]=> object(Stripe\Util\Set)#51 (1) { ["_elts":"Stripe\Util\Set":private]=> array(0) { } } ["_retrieveOptions":protected]=> array(0) { } } ["balance_transaction"]=> string(18) "txn_5wTdG5iWhmnXvG" ["failure_message"]=> NULL ["failure_code"]=> NULL ["amount_refunded"]=> int(0) ["customer"]=> string(18) "cus_5wTdY1eJMv14Vn" ["invoice"]=> NULL ["description"]=> NULL ["dispute"]=> NULL ["metadata"]=> object(Stripe\AttachedObject)#52 (5) { ["_opts":protected]=> object(Stripe\Util\RequestOptions)#36 (2) { ["headers"]=> array(0) { } ["apiKey"]=> string(32) "sk_07C5ukIdqxyDGFqIKB8f7TXqGGyQt" } ["_values":protected]=> array(0) { } ["_unsavedValues":protected]=> object(Stripe\Util\Set)#56 (1) { ["_elts":"Stripe\Util\Set":private]=> array(0) { } } ["_transientValues":protected]=> object(Stripe\Util\Set)#57 (1) { ["_elts":"Stripe\Util\Set":private]=> array(0) { } } ["_retrieveOptions":protected]=> array(0) { } } ["statement_descriptor"]=> NULL ["fraud_details"]=> array(0) { } ["receipt_email"]=> NULL ["receipt_number"]=> NULL ["shipping"]=> NULL ["application_fee"]=> NULL ["statement_description"]=> NULL ["fee"]=> int(132) ["fee_details"]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(Stripe\Object)#55 (5) { ["_opts":protected]=> object(Stripe\Util\RequestOptions)#36 (2) { ["headers"]=> array(0) { } ["apiKey"]=> string(32) "sk_07C5ukIdqxyDGFqIKB8f7TXqGGyQt" } ["_values":protected]=> array(5) { ["amount"]=> int(132) ["currency"]=> string(3) "usd" ["type"]=> string(10) "stripe_fee" ["description"]=> string(22) "Stripe processing fees" ["application"]=> NULL } ["_unsavedValues":protected]=> object(Stripe\Util\Set)#59 (1) { ["_elts":"Stripe\Util\Set":private]=> array(0) { } } ["_transientValues":protected]=> object(Stripe\Util\Set)#60 (1) { ["_elts":"Stripe\Util\Set":private]=> array(0) { } } ["_retrieveOptions":protected]=> array(0) { } } } } ["_unsavedValues":protected]=> object(Stripe\Util\Set)#41 (1) { ["_elts":"Stripe\Util\Set":private]=> array(0) { } } ["_transientValues":protected]=> object(Stripe\Util\Set)#42 (1) { ["_elts":"Stripe\Util\Set":private]=> array(0) { } } ["_retrieveOptions":protected]=> array(0) { } } object(PDOStatement)#62 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(74) "UPDATE accounting SET active = 1, plan = :plan_var WHERE id = :session_var" }
```

Comment: If it is an object then would it help to serialize it when storing in the database? On a separate note: in _$_SESSION['PLAN'] === '2500'_ you prepare $sql2 twice.

Comment: @RyanVincent  Right now I am just trying to get it into the DB. I can format the data later. Yes, I prepare $sql2 twice for 2 different validations. a or b

Comment: I suggest you serialize the object so that you **can** store it in the database. PHP does not automatically store objects in 'blobs'.

Comment: I wouldn't bother with a blob for JSON. It's just text so use one of MySQL's large string types.

Comment: Can you echo the INSERT?